# How do I resolve the 'Stream connection lost' error when using RabbitMQ in Python?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, message-queue

hi guys i have problem with connection.channel() in python for rabbit-mq . when i run my code in send and receive connection close forcibly , this is the error

```
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)
```

how can i fix this . please help me step by step . thanks

i see this problem in other questions and answers really does not help me , i install rabbitmq over and over i run rabbitmq server and enable management but connection always forcibly closed . i think its my os problem it's windows 10 .  can fix this or should i use linux or docker ?

Comment: RAbbitMQ and Erlang versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the similar issue while attempting to run a simple RabbitMQ producer locally. Because my producer function is running on another machine, I discovered something relating to version. It worked perfectly once I adjusted the erlang version from Erlang 26 to Erlang 25.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

not gonna lie really don't know how  but i try a lot of things . i reinstall and stop every rabbit-mq node . i am in windows and run this

```
rabbitmqctl.bat stop
```

and every time stop one node i do over and over and then start server again

```
rabbitmq-server.bat start
```

and that work

in windows if don't give path and administrator you should go on this path
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.11.17\spin